# HERE autocomplete API cut the zipcode for UK addresses

Tags: here-api

Using search for UK addressed via HERE autocomplete API returns shorten post codes (last 2 symbols related to the unit are cut).
While search for the full post code returns the correct address and the HERE maps are also able to find the full post code.

I'm querying the address "Choyce Close 38":

```
GET https://autocomplete.search.hereapi.com/v1/autocomplete?apiKey=&q=choyce%20close%2038&lang=en&limit=1

{
    "items": [
        {
            "title": "United Kingdom, LE67 3, Coalville, 38 Choyce Close",
            "id": "here:af:streetsection:E77KSGCrId.g46fwNvmTSC:CggIBCDom-OxAxABGgIzOA",
            "language": "en",
            "resultType": "houseNumber",
            "houseNumberType": "PA",
            "address": {
                "label": "38 Choyce Close, Coalville, LE67 3, United Kingdom",
                "countryCode": "GBR",
                "countryName": "United Kingdom",
                "state": "England",
                "countyCode": "LEC",
                "county": "Leicestershire",
                "city": "Coalville",
                "district": "Coalville",
                "street": "Choyce Close",
                "postalCode": "LE67 3",
                "houseNumber": "38"
            },
            "highlights": {
                "title": [
                    {
                        "start": 35,
                        "end": 37
                    },
                    {
                        "start": 38,
                        "end": 50
                    }
                ],
                "address": {
                    "label": [
                        {
                            "start": 0,
                            "end": 2
                        },
                        {
                            "start": 3,
                            "end": 15
                        }
                    ],
                    "street": [
                        {
                            "start": 0,
                            "end": 12
                        }
                    ],
                    "houseNumber": [
                        {
                            "start": 0,
                            "end": 2
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

and the post code from return is "LE67 3".

While the correct and common for UK is "LE67 3SS" post code
https://www.doogal.co.uk/ShowMap?postcode=LE67%203SS

Search for the full postcode returns the address however:

```
GET https://autocomplete.search.hereapi.com/v1/autocomplete?apiKey=&q=LE67%203SS&lang=en&limit=1

{
    "items": [
        {
            "title": "United Kingdom, Coalville, LE67 3SS Choyce Close",
            "id": "here:af:streetsection:E77KSGCrId.g46fwNvmTSC:EAMyCGxlNjd8M3Nz",
            "language": "en",
            "resultType": "postalCodePoint",
            "address": {
                "label": "LE67 3SS Choyce Close, Coalville, United Kingdom",
                "countryCode": "GBR",
                "countryName": "United Kingdom",
                "state": "England",
                "countyCode": "LEC",
                "county": "Leicestershire",
                "city": "Coalville",
                "district": "Coalville",
                "street": "Choyce Close",
                "postalCode": "LE67 3SS"
            },
            "highlights": {
                "title": [
                    {
                        "start": 27,
                        "end": 35
                    }
                ],
                "address": {
                    "label": [
                        {
                            "start": 0,
                            "end": 8
                        }
                    ],
                    "postalCode": [
                        {
                            "start": 0,
                            "end": 8
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

**What I need is to get correct full postcode returned while searching for the street name + building**

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this particular issue will not be solved in the near future, as at present we have no available source to link the full version of the postal code, LE67 3SS, to 38 Choyce Close.

The source we do have doesn't include the road in question, meaning that we cannot provide a link, further means that Autocomplete API will continue to return the results previously shown (LE67 3).

We include the full postal code as part of the UK Full Postal Code products, and we have the full point address coverage in the core map. We are now exploring different methods to try and create our own coverage to help remove this type of issue within Geocode & Search v7 service which may need more time and is not yet guaranteed.

Answer (score 0):

This works now. HERE autocomplete returns the complete UK postal code for the address.
"q=Choyce Close 38" returns the address with postal code LE67 3SS.
"q=10 Downing St London" returns the address with postal code SW1A 2AA.